# Only select value according to highlighted cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying a code which would select a value from a Data Validation Dropdown list only if the cell, which is two blocks to its left, is highlighted. But I am not able to figure out how to do this. Can anyone help please? Thanks

I have the following code which is wrong but just as an example:

```
Sub AssignBided()
Worksheets("Monday").Select
With Worksheets("Monday")
    If Hilight.range("B12") = True Then
        range("B12").Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Select
        .Selection.Value = "ABC"
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

The code to highlight cells is as follows:

```
Sub Hilight(RNG As range, Hilight As Boolean)
    With RNG.Interior
        If Hilight Then
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = RGB(100, 250, 150)
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        Else
            .Pattern = xlNone
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The hilight Sub is used as follows:

```
Dim L8Product As String
Dim i As Long
Dim L8Rnge As range
L8Product = range("Line8_P_Mon")
'Line 8 Resource requirement code
'Determine if change was made in cell B39
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.range("Line8_P_Mon")) Is Nothing Then
        Hilight range("Line8_Hilight_Mon"), False
'Below Code searches in the KP and Osgood Table and then highlights the 
appropriate cells
    If Trim(L8Product) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("Products").range("KP_Table")                     
'searchs in the KP Table on Sheet Overtime_Pos_Table

            'The code below will search the KP table for the product that you will select from the Line 8 drop down
            Set L8Rnge = .Find(what:=L8Product, _
                            after:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            lookat:=xlWhole, _
                            searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                            searchdirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not L8Rnge Is Nothing Then
                    Hilight range("KP_Hilight_Mon"), True               
'Hilights the cells for the KP and the Prep material required
            Else: With Sheets("Products").range("Osgood_Table")
                    Set L8Rnge = .Find(what:=L8Product, _
                                    after:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                    lookat:=xlWhole, _
                                    searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                                    searchdirection:=xlNext, _
                                    MatchCase:=False)
                    If Not L8Rnge Is Nothing Then
                            Hilight range("Osgood_Hilight_Mon"), True   
'Hilights the cells for the Osgood and the Prep material required
                    End If
                  End With
            End If
        End With
    Else: Hilight range("Line8_Hilight_Mon"), False
    End If
End If
```

Hope the question is clear. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple function to check for highlighting...

```
'use a constant to store the highlight color, since it's used
'   in multiple places in your code
Const HIGHLIGHT_COLOR = 9894500 'RGB(100, 250, 150)

Sub AssignBided()
    With Worksheets("Monday")
        If IsHighlighted(.Range("B12")) Then
            .Range("B12").Offset(0, 2).Value = "ABC" 'changed offset from -2...
        End If
    End With
End Sub

'Is a cell highlighted? EDIT: changed the function name to IsHighlighted
Function IsHighlighted(c As Range)
    IsHighlighted = (c.Interior.Color = HIGHLIGHT_COLOR)
End Function


Sub Hilight(RNG As Range, Hilight As Boolean)
    With RNG.Interior
        If Hilight Then
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = HIGHLIGHT_COLOR '<< use contant here
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        Else
            .Pattern = xlNone
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is highlighted (click "Debug" when the error pops up)?

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I tried using it but it is giving an error: wrong number of arguments.
I have written the code as follows:
`Const HIGHLIGHT_COLOR = 9894500

Function Hilighted(c As range)
    Highlighted = (c.Interior.Color = HIGHLIGHT_COLOR)
End Function
Sub Highlighted()
    With Worksheets("Monday")
        If Highlighted(.range("B12")) Then
            .range("B12").Offset(0, -2).Value = "Baize, Artress L."
        End If
    End With
End Sub`

Comment: Sorry for the double comments, the line highlighted is this:
'Sub Highlighted()`

Comment: Do you already have a Sub called `Highlighted`?  My posted code only has a function with that name.

Comment: Even after I change the Sub name its still giving the error Sub or Function not defined. Highlighting the `Sub AssignBidded()`

Comment: Okay I figured out what was wrong with my iteration of code. Now its giving me `Application defined or object defined error` and highlights `.range("B12").Offset(0, -2).Value = "ABC"`

Comment: I didn't notice this when I posted, but you can't offset two columns to the left of column B...  what column would that be?

Comment: Got it running! Thank you for all your help and clarification!

Comment: You were right, I cannot offset two columns to left, it was a mistake in the code, soon as I replaced "-2" with "2" Voila!! it worked! :D

Comment: On the same topic if I have a list of names and i want to loop through them and assign them to only the highlighted cells how would you think I should go about this? I am really sorry for bothering about this.

Comment: Time for a new question?

Comment: I guess yes! New to the forum. Was blocked before for asking too many questions. Will do! Thanks...